# Elastic Search Update API by script in NEST 6.5.4 for .NET

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elastic-stack

I am using Nest 6.5.4. I am not able to perform Update with script on a particular document in an index.
I have tried many ways but I am getting a syntax error.
My query is as follows.

```
var clientProvider = new ElasticClientProvider();
var projectModel = new ProjectModel();
 var res = clientProvider.Client.Update<ProjectModel>(projectModel, i => i
                .Index("attachment_index")
                .Type("attachments")
                .Id(projectId)
.Script(script=>script.Source("ctx._source.fileInfo.fileViewCount= ctx._source.fileInfo.fileViewCount + 1"))
                );
```

It is throwing an error "Update Descriptor does not have a definition for Id"
The same query is working when tried in Kibana

```
POST attachment_index/attachments/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "source":"ctx._source.fileInfo.fileViewCount += 1"
  }
}
```

I dont know where I am getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.Id()` method on [`UpdateDescriptor<T, TPartial>`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/044f557e4ad5e48ccfb2aedda2a946d45ac8fc6a/src/Nest/_Generated/_Descriptors.generated.cs#L3705-L3764) because an id is a required parameter for an Update API call, so this constraint is enforced through the constructors.

The first parameter to `.Update<T>(...)` is a [`DocumentPath<T>`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/document-paths.html) from which an index, type and id can be derived for the update API call. If the `ProjectModel` CLR POCO has an `Id` property with a value, this will be used for Id of the call. For example

```
public class ProjectModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

var client = new ElasticClient();

var projectModel = new ProjectModel { Id = 1 };

var updateResponse = client.Update<ProjectModel>(projectModel, i => i
    .Index("attachment_index")
    .Type("attachments")
    .Script(script => script
        .Source("ctx._source.fileInfo.fileViewCount= ctx._source.fileInfo.fileViewCount + 1"))
);
```

which results in

```
POST http://localhost:9200/attachment_index/attachments/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.fileInfo.fileViewCount= ctx._source.fileInfo.fileViewCount + 1"
  }
}
```

If you want to explicitly specify the Id, you can pass the value for `DocumentPath<T>`

```
var updateResponse = client.Update<ProjectModel>(1, i => i
    .Index("attachment_index")
    .Type("attachments")
    .Script(script => script
        .Source("ctx._source.fileInfo.fileViewCount= ctx._source.fileInfo.fileViewCount + 1"))
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
client.UpdateAsync<ProjectModel, object>(
                new DocumentPath<ProjectModel>(id),
                u => u
                    .Index(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("indexname"))
                    .Type(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("indextype"))
                    .Doc(ProjectModel)
                    .DocAsUpsert()
                    .Refresh(Elasticsearch.Net.Refresh.True));
```

This will work and let me know if you are still facing any issues.